# Rename files in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cmd

I would like to rename all files in my Amazon S3 bucket with extension.PDF to .pdf (lowercase).

Did someone already have to do this? There are a lot of files (around 1500). Is S3cmd the best way to do this? How would you do?

Comment: Please note that you can't actually rename uploaded files. You can only copy them with new names

Answer (score 1):

```
  s3cmd --recursive ls s3://bucketname |
        awk '{ print $4 }' | grep "*.pdf"  | while read -r line ; do

s3cmd --recursive mv s3://<s3_bucketname>/$line/ s3://<s3_bucketname>/${line%.*}".PDF"

done
```

A local linux/unix example for renaming all files with `.pdf` extension to `.PDF` extension.

```
mkdir pdf-test
cd pdf-test
touch a{1..10}.pdf
```

Before

```
 ls
    a1.pdf  a2.pdf  a4.pdf  a6.pdf  a8.pdf  grep.sh
    a10.pdf a3.pdf  a5.pdf  a7.pdf  a9.pdf
```

The script file **grep.sh**

```
#/bin/bash
ls |grep .pdf | while read -r line ; do # here use ls from s3
    echo "Processing $line"
    # your s3 code goes here
    mv $line ${line%.*}".PDF"
done
```

Add permissions and try

```
 chmod u+x grep.sh

./grep.sh
```

After

```
ls
a1.PDF  a2.PDF  a4.PDF  a6.PDF  a8.PDF  grep.sh
a10.PDF a3.PDF  a5.PDF  a7.PDF  a9.PDF
```

You can apply the same logic. instead of `mv` use s3 `mv`.

Comment: the problems are : how to find files with .PDF, and how to make this loop with s3cmd ?

Comment: commands might need some alterations, I don't have access to s3 to test but you can give it a try.

Comment: I did not succeed to make the command work. It is supposed to replace all ".PDF" by ".pdf "in files names ?

Comment: logic is fetching the the files with `.pdf` extension and then apply the `mv` command in a loop to rename them. I will try to put a local version of the same so that you will get an idea. You can apply the same to the s3 `mv`.

Comment: I get the message "bad substitution". You know where it could come from ?

Comment: Kindly share the code you tried. The local code which I pasted has been tested on my machine and it is working correctly for me.

Comment: I'm using s3cmd and I tried this : s3cmd --recursive ls s3://mybucket | grep .PDF | while read -r line ; do mv $line ${$line.%*}.pdf

Comment: `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive | awk '{print $4}` what is the output of this? you have to do mv of s3 not your local mv

Comment: it's getting better. Now I get "mv : target 0c9f39e3c8e2b94981b8ec2cac4858f0.PDF.pdf is not a directory" when I try aws s3 ls s3://bucketpreprodscoplan --recursive | grep ".PDF" | while read -r line ; do mv $ine ${line%.}".pdf"; done